# Python - search element in the list inside dataframe rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to capture the elements inside the data frame / pandas that is in list format. Below captures the entire list if the string exists, how do I only capture elements by row for a particular string and ignore the rest?

Here is what I tried...

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
l2 = ['hello world \n my world','world is a great place \n we live in it','planet earth',np.NaN,'\n save the water','']

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(l1,l2)),
            columns=['id','sentence'])
df['sentence_split'] = df['sentence'].str.split('\n')
print(df)
```

result of this code:

```
df[df.sentence_split.str.join(' ').str.contains('world', na=False)]  # does the trick but still not exactly what I am looking for. 


id  sentence                                  sentence_split
1   hello world \n my world                   [hello world , my world]
2   world is a great place \n we live in it   [world is a great place , we live in it]
```

but looking for:

```
id  sentence                                  sentence_split
1   hello world \n my world                   hello world; my world
2   world is a great place \n we live in it   world is a great place
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to search for a string in a list in a series. One approach is to:

```
# Drop NaN rows
df = df.dropna(subset=["sentence_split"])
```

Apply a function that only preserves the elements in the lists you are looking for

```
# Apply this lamda function
df["sentence_split"] = df["sentence_split"].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if "world" in i])

   id                                 sentence             sentence_split
0   1                  hello world \n my world  [hello world ,  my world]
1   2  world is a great place \n we live in it  [world is a great place ]
2   3                             planet earth                         []
4   5                        \n save the water                         []
5   6                                                                  []
```